# Final rendering image with blurred red color

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, texturing, image

I am new to blender.

Whenever my render finishes 100% it appears a blurred red on my image, that only happens at the end and while the render is happening everything is looks fine.
Also, another question, if you see in the image, the first wheel turns out different from the others and I am using the same texture for all of them, why is that happening?

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: What's the compositor look like?

Comment: Not sure why you have there the red blur, but the wheel probably have a bad or non existing UVs

Comment: Yes, compositor was actually with a glossy node, haha

Comment: and for the wheel, yes, I didn't do UVs for them. Beginner miskates.. Thanks, guys.